# Should we close questions with many upvotes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Many of the questions asked but have received a few close votes have +10 or more net upvotes.

Now since we are in private beta, an upvote indicates approval of a question.

So if 6 more users have indicated that the question is a good question, should we still vote to close such questions (which require only 5 close votes)?

Comment: you only have 2 questions with 10+ votes. having 1 of your questions be up for closure that has 10+ does not constitute as "many"

Answer (score 7):

People upvote questions for all kinds of reasons. They might think it's interesting. They might want to give the asker reputation (yes this happens). They *might* think it's a good question for the beta. Or they might have just seen a kitten and are really happy.

The point is, *people vote however they like for whatever reason*. Score is absolutely not to be taken as a strict indicator of quality.

Closing, on the other hand, is a more concrete process. There are close *reasons*. If a question fits one of these reasons, by all means close it.

Don't take into account score when voting to close or leave open a question. Just look at the content and make your decision from there based on current guidelines.